# Sparql identifying Powerstations more precisely

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I would like to get all powerstations and also the type of powerstation (Nuclear, Water, Coal etc...) from DBpedia.

I recognized that there are no specific types of powerstations, so I am query all powerstations and try to figure out the type of powerstation from the name. ( I will not catch all of them, but a lot enough).

My query so far :

```
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbp-ont: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
#PREFIX georss: <http://www.georss.org/georss/>

select distinct *
{
?name rdf:type dbp-ont:PowerStation .
?name geo:lat ?lat .
?name geo:long ?long
OPTIONAL { ?name  dbo:installedCapacity ?installedCapacity }
OPTIONAL { ?name  dbo:openingDate ?openingDate }
OPTIONAL { ?name  dbo:closingDate ?closingDate }
} limit 100
```

Is there a way to have a new field named 'nuclear' that has a value of '1' if its name contains 'nuclear' ?

Comment: `BIND(if(contains(lcase(str(?name)), "nuclear"), 1, 0) as ?nuclear)`

Comment: Thank you very much. That helps me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is to remember that [DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) data is a moving target, just like the Wikipedia data from which it is derived. Updates to Wikipedia will eventually (typically, in 3-9 months) be part of DBpedia. More quickly (typically in a few hours, if not minutes or seconds; sometimes days, for various reasons), they'll be part of [DBpedia-Live](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql).

The long-term solution for giving every powerstation a type as you wish, is to edit Wikipedia.

For your specific immediate workaround, note that a large number of `OPTIONAL` clauses can make your query take much longer, and so may eventually mean that DBpedia will not return the data you want.  You may need to spin up your own mirror (such as [DBpedia](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B07BQKYGYQ) or [DBpedia-Live](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B012DSCFEK) in the Amazon EC2 Cloud).

Finally, as @AKSW noted in comments, the line below should deliver your `?nuclear` variable with a `1` if that string appeared in the `?name`.  Just put it after your `OPTIONAL` lines.

```
BIND ( IF ( CONTAINS ( LCASE ( STR ( ?name ) ), "nuclear" ), 1, 0 ) AS ?nuclear )
```